# How to fetch the data from the google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am creating Dialogflow app and I want to send SMS at some point of flow. For that I am thinking of storing the recepient's phone number in excel and place this excel in google cloud storage . how can I get the phone data from that excel ?

Comment: This doesn't seem very efficient.  Why wouldn't you use a database that you can easily query?

Comment: No , My requirement is to take the data from excel which I get from client. can I use google spreadsheets ? if so, please let me know how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the file in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) as you mentioned, and use, for example, the PHP Client library [1] for GCS along with PHPExcel [2].

You will find it very easy to read and extract data from Excel files using PHP.

You can also use PHP-ExcelReader [3], which also reads Excel .xls files. PHPExcel can also manage .xlsx files.

I have found this tutorial [4] which helps to illustrate how to read Excel files using PHPExcel.

You could run your PHP application from (for example) Compute Engine [5], App Engine [6]. Please, take a look at this reference [7] which illustrates how to deploy PHP applications on Google Cloud Platform.

I would also like to recommend this Bucket and Object Naming Guidelines reference [8]. Please visit this tutorial [9] on how to create buckets and upload objects.

Do not forget to take a look at GCS Authentication [10] so that you may be able to gain and manage access to the service.

Let me know how it goes.

---

Links:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php

[2] https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

[3] https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader

[4] http://www.techchattr.com/how-to-read-excel-files-with-php

[5] https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine

[6] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/

[7] https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/

[8] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#top_of_page

[9] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil

[10] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication